# how to create clone of an object which does not implement Cloneable

Tags: java, applet, clone, jcchart

I have to clone an object which does not implement Cloneable interface how to do this.

Actually in my project I am using JCChart .now my class extends MultiChart and I have to craete the deep copy of my class. I am able to clone my class object but how to clone Objects of MultiChart. like I also have to clone Legends of objects , Footer of Object, Header of Object.

Comment: See if you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: but I am doing this in applet so can't serialize the object due to restriction on applet to access the file system

Comment: make the your object implementing Cloneable interface and implement deep copy on your own.

Comment: to deep copy I have to create clone of legends of chart for which I am using chartClone.setLegend(chart.getLegend().clone()) but since JCLegend does not implement Cloneable interface that's why I am becoming unable to clone the legends. How can I do this

Comment: You should be able to serialize to an in-memory stream, such as a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class is `Serializable` than you can [serialize the object to ByteStream](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/SerializeObj.html) and [Deserialize that stream to a new object](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/DeserializeObj.html).

Comment: I try this but give exception
java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents

I think writeObject is unable to write the the data

Comment: @user571616, if any of the class in your objectmap is not serialzable, than it will throw java.io.NotSerializableException  exception. (i.e, if your class A contains object of class B & C; And class A implements Serializable & B does not, than while serializing an object of class A will throw this exception - saying classB is not serializable)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> I have to clone an object which does not implement `Cloneable` interface how to do this.

The requirement for clone to work is that the class provides a `clone()` method that is *visible* in the context that you want to call it.  That class does not `have to` implement `Cloneable`.  It could implement the `clone()` method to explicitly use `new` and then initialize the new object via the constructor and setter calls.  (The `Cloneable` interface is a "flag" interface that enables the default shallow cloning mechanism implemented by the `java.lang.Object.clone()` method.)

---

On the topic of cloning without using clone, alternatives include:

- using a copy constructor,
- using a regular constructor and a sequence of getter and setter calls, or
- by serializing and deserializing the object.

These approaches all have limitations; e.g. availability of appropriate constructors, getters, setters, or serializability.  Implementing deep cloning using the first two approaches can be very coding intensive.  The last approach tends to be significantly more expensive, but it is the easiest way to give you a deep copy of a complex data structure ... if that's what you need.

> ... but I am doing this in applet so can't serialize the object due to restriction on applet to access the file system.

Java object serialization (using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`) and [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) can both write objects to streams that are backed by in-memory buffers; e.g. `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  This avoids the need to access the file system ... and will be faster.

Comment: Whn I use ByteArrayOutputStream to for serialization then at that time it give the following java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents
I think the image is not loaded at the time of serialization so what should I do for this

Answer (score 0):

Well, one alternative is to provide a copy constructor, and honestly, given the extralinguistic nature of Java's clone implementation I tend to prefer this option.

The copy constructor consists of a constructor that receives, as it single parameter, another instance of its same type. Then you go field by field doing the corresponding copying.

When you do this kind of thing, you must take immutability into account to avoid problems.

Another approach is to serialize your object, and then deserialize it, but this implies that you would need to implement Serializable, which is not always an option and it is not free of certain implications.

Comment: Too much manual work for complex instance graphs. Serialization is so much easier. Serializable interface is only required for default serialization. There are others available.

Comment: A copy constructor doesn't work if the class type is unknown at compile time. ie, you can't use a copy constructor to dynamically clone an object.